# How can I use two functions of the same name in model django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have two functions in the same model , and I need to use them in my generic view , one function in a view and the other function in the other view .

```
class Container(models.Model):
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE ,null=True)
    . 
    .
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    Free_volume = models.FloatField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):#the first function
        return reverse('vehicule_app:container-view')

    def get_absolute_url(self):#the secont function
        return reverse('vehicule_app:details', kwargs={'pk' : self.pk})
```

I want to use the first function in this view :

```
form_class = ContainerForm
template_name = 'vehicule_app/container_form.html'
```

and I want to use the second function in other view  :

```
class ContainerCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = ContainerForm
    template_name = 'vehicule_app/container_form.html'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your function. They do not return the same choice. They do not need to have the same name.

```
def get_absolute_container_url(self):
    return reverse('vehicule_app:container-view')

def get_absolute_details_url(self):
    return reverse('vehicule_app:details', kwargs={'pk' : self.pk})
```

If you want only one function, you can add an optional parameter.

```
def get_absolute_url(self, get_details=False):
    if get_details:
        return reverse('vehicule_app:details', kwargs={'pk' : self.pk})
    else:
        return reverse('vehicule_app:container-view')
```

In your views:

```
class ContainerCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = ContainerForm
    template_name = 'vehicule_app/container_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
         # This function is call when form is valid.
         # Put your code here
```

Comment: i need only one function , i understand the function that you wrote , but it's work one time , it can't change the value false to true .
maybe i need to change something on my urls .

Comment: Did you call it like this : get_absolute_url(get_details=True) you need to specify the parameter in call.

Comment: where i have to call it ? in view.py ?
 look what i did : class ContainerCreate(CreateView):

    form_class = ContainerForm
    template_name = 'vehicule_app/container_form.html'
    get_absolute_url(get_details=True)

Comment: wow... you need to understand how view works. When do you want call this function? When form is valid ??  You can override 
    def form_valid(self, form) function in your view. And put your call here. CHekc my answer

Comment: thank you bro , it's work now but i did it with success_url , thank you so much. in understand how your code work

Comment: Good. Yes, succes_url is call after form_valid. So it's a good solution too. :)